# cant call more than one common functions from main class when run in remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have to call multiple functions from Class1.cs file. But when calling more than one functions from this class it shows error on REMOTE SERVER.But runs well in LOCAL SERVER.
It works on remote server if we call only one function.
I have tried out like this way,

In main class,

```
public class Class1
{
public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2)
{
    int result = number1 + number2;
    return result;
}
public int subNumbers(int number1, int number2)
{
    int result = number1 - number2;
    return result;
}
}
```

in Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
Class1 obj = new Class1();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void bt_sum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32( tb_num1.Text);
    int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(tb_num2.Text);
    int sum= obj.AddNumbers(num1,num2);
    lb_sum.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);

}
protected void BT_DIFF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(tb_num1.Text);
    int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(tb_num2.Text);
    int sum = obj.subNumbers(num1, num2);
    lb_sum.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);

}
}
```

its url is, `http://www.edugame.co/trial/Default.aspx

What will be the reason ?please help`

Comment: You mean this error? ` CS1061: 'Class1' does not contain a definition for 'subNumbers' and no extension method 'subNumbers' accepting a first argument of type 'Class1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Please provide all relevant details when asking for help.

Comment: My guess is that the remote server has an old version of Class1...

Comment: Could you share the page_load event code ?

Comment: there is nothing written  on page load event @ Muthukumar

Answer (score 2):

I tried with your code. But found nothing wrong .

```
int sum = obj.subNumbers(num1, num2);
```

Works fine. Please rebuild the project contains Class1. And host it again

Comment: I have rebuild and tried it lot of times. But shows the same problem.

Comment: Remove all old dll s  from server ,  then host new one. May be your hosting tool is not replacing the old files (files already exists). There is no other possibilities .Best of luck. thanks